# Step file property mapping

Tags: autodesk-model-derivative

When I load a STEP model into inventor, during the import processing these is the opportunity to perform property mapping. In my case, specifically "material" property.

Is there similar functionality available when loading Step models into Forge?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, unfortunately, only the options listed in the **documentation** are available:
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/

If the mapping can be automated using the **Inventor API** (not sure), then perhaps you could use the **Design Automation API** to import the **STEP** file into an **Inventor** document and then translate that to **SVF** which then could be displayed in the **Viewer**

Comment: Thanks Adam, sounds like a big job.

Comment: Also, STEP file is just a text file. Would it not be possible to change property names that way? Did you try?